Edge read aloud doesn't read screen reader only elements
Most guides for providing css classes for screen reader only elements suggest something like the following (from https://medium.com/web-dev-survey-from-kyoto/the-visually-hidden-technique-303f8e2bd409):
.visually-hidden { 
  /* Contain text within 1px box */
  height: 1px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  /* Keep the layout */  
  position: absolute;
  /* Remove any visible trace (e.g. background color) */
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%); /* browsers in the future */
  /* Prevent the screen reader to skip spaces between words */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

However, Edge's "Read aloud" function will not read text inside a visually-hidden element.
For example, Edge Read Aloud will only read "Lucy Bob" given the following html:
<p>
  Lucy
  <span style="height: 1px; width: 1px; position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); clip-path: inset(50%); white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden">and</span>
  Bob
</p>

Removing the overflow property will get Edge to read "Lucy and Bob", but will lead to horizontal scrollbars when the hidden element is long enough, e.g.:
<p>
  Lucy
  <span style="height: 1px; width: 1px; position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); clip-path: inset(50%); white-space: nowrap">and Mary and Sue and Jemima and Zog and Olivia and Yog-Sothoth and foo and Ashurbanipal and Tutankhamun and Kamehameha the Great and Felipe Juan Pablo Alfonso de Todos los Santos de Borbón y Grecia and Mary and Sue and Jemima and Zog and Olivia and Yog-Sothoth and foo and Ashurbanipal and Tutankhamun and Kamehameha the Great and Felipe Juan Pablo Alfonso de Todos los Santos de Borbón y Grecia</span>
  Bob
</p>

will lead to a horizontal scrollbar on my screen.
Is there a solution that will not insert a horizontal scrollbar but will be read by Edge's Read Aloud feature?

It seems that only the solution that moves elements to the farthest left position works in Edge. You can refer to the code sample below, Edge will read the hidden element:


.screenreader {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
<p>
  Lucy
  <span class="screenreader">and Mary and Sue and Jemima and Zog and Olivia and Yog-Sothoth and foo and Ashurbanipal and Tutankhamun and Kamehameha the Great and Felipe Juan Pablo Alfonso de Todos los Santos de Borbón y Grecia and Mary and Sue and Jemima and Zog and Olivia and Yog-Sothoth and foo and Ashurbanipal and Tutankhamun and Kamehameha the Great and Felipe Juan Pablo Alfonso de Todos los Santos de Borbón y Grecia</span>  Bob
</p>



